# Use Dash with websockets

Tags: websocket, callback, plotly, real-time, plotly-dash

What is the best way to use Dash with Websockets to build a real-time dashboard ? I would like to update a graph everytime a message is received but the only thing I've found is calling the callback every x seconds like the example below.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_daq as daq
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from websocket import create_connection
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
import json
import ssl


# Setting up the websocket and the necessary web handles
ws = create_connection(address, sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1*1000,
            n_intervals=0)
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])

def update_graph_live(n):

    message = ws.recv()
    x=message.get('data1')
    y=message.get('data2')
        .....


    fig = go.Figure(
        data = [go.Bar(x=x,y=y)],
        layout=go.Layout(
            title=go.layout.Title(text="Bar Chart")
            )
        )
    )

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Is there a way to trigger the callback everytime a message is received (maybe storing them in a database before) ?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the `Websocket` component from the `Dash Extensions` package. As you can see at the [example](https://www.dash-extensions.com/components/websocket), the package provides a `WebSocket` component that is included in your app's layout. Messages can be received in callbacks by the `message` property of `WebSocket`.

Regarding this, the solution to your problem would be like:

```
from dash_extensions import WebSocket
from dash_extensions.enrich import callback, dcc, html, Input, Output, DashProxy
# all dash imports are replaced by dash_extensions
import plotly.graph_objs as go

app = DashProxy(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        WebSocket(id='ws', url="ws:...")  # Websocket address is inserted here
    ]
)

@callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
          Input('ws', 'message'))
def update_graph_live(msg):
    # Parsing msg depends on its structure, e.g.:
    x = msg['x']
    y = msg['y']

    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[go.Bar(x=x,y=y)],
        layout=go.Layout(
            title=go.layout.Title(text="Bar Chart")
        )
    )
    return fig
```

The link above delivers further details about this topic, e.g. about the websocket setup.

Answer (score 0):

This forum post describes a method to use websocket callbacks with Dash:

https://community.plot.ly/t/triggering-callback-from-within-python/23321/6

#### Update

Tried it, it works well. Environment is Windows 10 x64 + Python 3.7.

To test, download the `.tar.gz` file and run `python usage.py`. It will complain about some missing packages, install these. Might have to edit the address from `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` in `usage.py`. Browse to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` to see the results. If I had more time, I'd put this example up on GitHub (ping me if you're having trouble getting it to work, or the original gets lost).

Comment: Hey contango, I chanced upon your answer and would like to ask a little more about it. Do you mind if we chat for a bit?

Comment: @jtan354 Sure. I did get it to work but never used it in the end. It will publish the same information out to every connected client. What do you use for chat?

Comment: Hey contango thank you for your reply. However, I managed to get it to work so there is no need to trouble you. Thanks for offering to help! :)

Comment: @jtan354 Great! Glad you have a solution. If you can post any extra information as another answer for the latest version of Dash it would help to pay it forward :) Even the versions of Dash you used would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I had two separate servers: one for dash, the other one as a socket server. They are running on different ports. On receiving a message, I edited a common json file to share information to dash's callback. That's how I did it.