# Python Dash table live updates: Any alternate to Interval?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, intervals

I am making a dash board with a table using python dash. I want it to be updated every time i gather data in the backgroud. The problem is I cant use the dcc.Interval as my data gathering can take bit longer sometimes, so I cant set periodic updates.
Is there any other alternatives?
Can I use the change in table data itself as a trigger to fire callback again? I tried that, but below code is not working.

```
@app.callback(Output('table','data'),
              Output('table', 'style_data_conditional'),
              Input('table','data'))
def updateTable(ignore):
   return get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

The table can't change itself, or it would just create an infinite loop.

Some options:

- You could set the interval to much much larger, like every minute or 2 minutes
- You could use a button to manually trigger an update each time the user clicks it
- You could also look into using web sockets. See some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860270/use-dash-with-websockets) and [here](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions/blob/master/examples/websocket_push.py). That would require something external to be able to send a message to your Dash app, though